# Apache POI: Identify raw tables in excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a excel sheet that looks like this.

[image]

I wish to traverse this file and point out the start and end of the different tables. for eg: table 1 => a1:b2, table 2 => d1:g2. There can be multiple such tables.

I am looking for the algorithm or steps to get this done. i can code it myself then. The issue here is that i am scanning the excel sheet row by column so once i encountered b1 as the end of the first table I traverse down to a2 and b2. Later i need to jump back to row 1 and scan for table 2.

Comment: Maybe you could give some background information why you want to identify those tables. Do you want to extract data of those generated reports or set the cell styles ...? Do you have control over the generation itself?

Comment: The above file is a template file. Once i am able to identify the tables i create a structure and then use it to traverse another excel file which has data in it. This template file is basically a mapping between the column headers etc to actual data. Does it make sense?

Comment: Use first row in your template to mark begin and end of the tables. For example (from your picture) don't merge header report _name but mark begin of first table in `A1` and end in `B1`, mark the begin of second table in `D1` and end in `G1`. Then read row 1 to determinate the tables starts/ends. If done, then you have this information and then you can delete the marks and merge header report _name programmatically.

Comment: You could also use `Names` which refers to the first table rows. Apache poi can read those names and its refers-to-formula using `Workbook.getAllNames()`.
Btw.: You know that a `Excel` workbook can contain multiple sheets? Why not using a separate sheet for each table?

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for the workaround of heading markers for table start and end. I am going to try that now. And yes,  you are right about excel having multiple worksheets. But, in my case multiple worksheets may have multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you may have to do everything manually. You can't assign tables values, only cells.